# getting an error in String line = x.readLine();

Tags: java, netbeans, io, filereader

i'm getting a little problem in filereading

here's the code

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader ("products.txt"); {
String line = fr.readLine();

while(line != null){
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

NetBeans giving me an error at

> String line = fr.readLine();

especially under readLine();

i tried nextLine, but didn't work too.

thank you for the help

Comment: Did you check the documentation of `FileReader` class for what all method it has?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because, [**FileReader**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) doesnt have `readLine()` method, you should use [**BufferedReader**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) instead.

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader ("products.txt"); 
Bufferedreader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String line = null;

while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.
but we haven't take bufferedreader in class :/
this is part of an assignment too

Comment: @AbdelrahmanM.Alhajj you are welcome, if you are not allowed to use Bufferedreader you could always use FileReader.read() method, but BufferedReader is highy efficient when compared to Filereader.

Comment: not sure about that method, can you convert mine into it.. if it's not a bother

Comment: @AbdelrahmanM.Alhajj check the API my friend. its always better place for you to learn. also read java tutorial regarding reading a file using buffered reader, i am pretty sure there are 1000's examples on google...:) good luck :)

Answer (score 3):

the error because FileReader doesn't have the readLine() function

try this :

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("products.txt"));

String line = null;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`FileReader` does not have the method `readLine`.

You may want to use a `BufferedReader`.